# Compare two rows from DataTable by their indexes

Tags: c#, excel, linq, datatable, datarow

I have filled DataTable.
In each row I try to find some string value which must be unique. If I find row with that value, I need to go down (skip some rows) till I find row with some const string like `Expr1`. Now I need to return all row that contains `Expr1`.

So there are two conditions:

1 - find row `Row1` with input value.
2 - find closest row to `Row1` that contains const value `Expr1` and return it.

```
InputValueToFind|
Week1           | 1
Week2           | 2
Week3           | 3
Total           | 6

Expr1           | 4
```

It is how my Excel file looks (all data from Excel file I write to datatable)

---

```
DataRow[] netPay = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row[0].ToString().Trim().ToLower().Equals("Expr1".ToLower())).ToArray();
```

This code return all rows from DataTable that contains `Expr1`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim().ToLower().Equals(inputVal.ToLower()))
                            {
                                // do some stuff
                            }
                        }
```

Using this code I can get row with `InputValue`.

Problem - now I don't know how to find closest row with `Expr1` to row with `InputValue` (in other words, I don't know how to use these two blocks of code together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do **Select** on the IEnumerable, there is an optional generic int `TIn` parameter, which you can use in the following manner.

```
Select<DataRow, int, KeyValuePair<int, DataRow>>((row,idx) => new KeyValePair<int, DataRow>(idx, row)
```

Using that type, you can perform your index (proximity) checks easier.

---

I would create my own object(s) types for this though

```
public class IndexDataRowPair
{
    public int Index {get;set;}
    public DataRow Row {get;set;}

    // or, just the values you intend to use
    // public string InputValue {get;set;}
    // public string ExpressionValue {get;set;}
}

...

// generic Select<TIn, Tin, TResult> parameters will be inferred:= 
// Select<DataRow, int, IndexDataRowPair> 
dt.Select((row,idx) => new IndexDataRowPair() { Index = idx, Row = row });
```

Comment: but to get real index for row i should do filtering after select. Am i correct?

Comment: @demo, that's correct, yes .. for performing the select after filter will provide you the index of the remaining collection, and that wouldn't be helpful in your scenerio...